# Search a content type fields based on user inputs

Tags: search

I am using Drupal 7.
I need to create a search condition to generate a search result.I have a content type called "properties".It contains around 20 fields like Location,City,Availability,Property type,Category,Price,Nearby Landmarks,amenities etc...

I have a search form to search properties based on 
PropertyCategory
PropertyType
City
Location
Price
Furnish  etc...

But drupal generates separate tables for each field type.How can i retrieve data from all table based on any search condition?I have created a view based on this content type "properties".

Do we have any option to generate a single table for a content type?
Could you please give me an idea.
Please help me ,i am stuck on the way and can't move without any help.

Thanks in advance!

harikris.

Answer (score 0):

If you want result from a specific content type then user views with expose filter for search and filter it with the specific content type. 
Why do you need single table for all the fields, Either you can use join to fetch data from all the table. You should not write custom code for this kind of functionality best option is to alter the search query or user views with expose filter to provide this functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the reply .let check with your suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply .
This is the website that needs search functions...   w3qatar.info/alderarcs.
I need a property search feature here...Do you have any suggestion to make this form working?

regards,
Harikris.

Comment: I found some search APIs.Can we use Multi-index searches ,Finder and search api?